# Jquery tooltip always showing head title name as tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm using the built-in Jquery tooltip library and it works great, EXCEPT in Firefox, it always shows the title of the page (inside `<head>`, like so: `<title>My Title</title></head>`).

I've tried to use the "disabled: true" option and it still shows. Any clue how I can hide this?

I initialize it with this line:

```
$(function() {
   $( document ).tooltip({ position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" } });
   $('.head-title').tooltip( "option", "disabled", true );
});
```

I've tried the following two disable methods, neither of which worked. I wrapped the title in another div called "head-title"

```
$('.head-title').tooltip({ disabled: true });
$('.head-title').tooltip('disabled');
$('.head-title').tooltip( "option", "disabled", true );
```

I'm using JQuery v1.8.2.

Comment: Can you copy your HTML source ? It looks like you have something not closed

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, but I can assure you everything is closed properly. I updated it with the entire javascript portion, though.

Comment: Yeah, it's almost certainly an HTML error. Post some code!

Comment: Ok so try with a minimalist code then put back block by block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close but it is `.tooltip('disable')`, not `.tooltip('disabled')`.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( document ).tooltip('disable');
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/5F3kf/18/

Comment: There were actually two issues. The first one was the one that Dom mentioned. The second was that the `$(document)` selector in the tooltip instantiation was causing issues along with the disables. I had to change the selector to `$('*')`, then everything worked beautifully

Answer (score 0):

There were actually two issues. The first one was the one that Dom mentioned. The second was that the `$(document)` selector was causing issues along with the disables. I had to change the selector to `$('*')`, then everything worked beautifully

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the "body" tag only to apply your tooltip .. just write it this way and it will work for sure:

```
$( "body" ).tooltip();
```

instead of this:

```
$( document ).tooltip();
```